# Order 2 differential equations and linearly dependent solutions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have difficulties to resolve the following exercice. I try with Wronski, but i haven't obtain good result.

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ two linearly independent solutions of the equation
$$
(P(x)y')'+q(x)y=0
$$
on the interval $[a,b]$ with $P(x) >0$.

1. Prouve that $y_1$ and $y_2$ do not vanish together in the same time.
2. Prouve that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are not equal to zero, and if they are linearly dependent, then $y_1$ and $y_2$ vanish together in the same time.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1.) If $y_1(x^*)=0=y_2(x^*)$, then 
$$
y(x)=αy_1(x)+βy_2(x) ~~ \text{ with } ~ α=y_2'(x^*),~ β=-y_1'(x^*),
$$
is a non-trivial linear combination with $y(x^*)=y'(x^*)=0$. As $α=0$ would imply $y_2(x^*)=0=y_2'(x^*)$, both coefficients are non-zero.

2.) is trivial as $y_2=cy_1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please, i don't understant 1. Can you more explain please. Why you choose $y_1'(t*)$ and $y_2'(t*)$ whith $y_1(t*)=0=y_2(t*)$. And another question, why we suppose that $P(x)>0$? And if $P(x) <0$?

Comment: 1.) to get $y'(t^*)=0$. Check again what linear dependence means, use the general definition in the context of more than 2 vectors. -- You have to exclude that $P(x)=0$ at some point in the interval, i.e., the sign stays constant, positive is the default.

Comment: $y_1$ et $y_2$ are linearly dependent means that $$\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}: \alpha y_1(x)+ \beta y_2(x)=0 => \alpha=\beta=0$$ you put $\alpha=y'_1(x*)$ and $\beta=y'_2(x*)$ with $y_1(x*)=0=y_2(x*)$. I don't understand

Comment: For a homogeneous second order linear DE, what does it mean for a solution $y$ if $y(x^*)=0$ and $y'(x^*)=0$? And if you look closer you will find that $α=y_2(x^*)$ and $β=-y_1'(x^*)$. Follow-up: Why would $α=0$ or $β=0$ be impossible?

Comment: it means that $y$ is equal to zero. How you remark that $\alpha= y_2(x*)$ and $\beta=-y'_1(x*)$. You use Wronski? I am very lost

Comment: @user415040 It's the other they way around. This is the linearly independence. If they are lineary dependend you can choose a solution with $\alpha\neq 0, \beta \neq 0$  If they are lineary independend. you only find the trivial solution. $\alpha = \beta = 0$